# How to associate two DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li> One <p> Foo is a fool. </p> </li>
    <li> Two <p> Bar is not Barbie. </p> </li>
    <li> Three <p> Baz likes bazookas. </p> </li>
</ul>

<div id="pane"></div>
```

As you can see, there is a UL list. Each LI item contains a paragraph that is at all times hidden.

What I want to do is this:
Whenever the user clicks a LI element, the corresponding P element should be transfered to the #pane DIV. And then, when the user clicks the same LI element again, the P element should be transfered back to its original location.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/u5y6u/1/

This is the jQuery code that I'm using currently:

```
var p;

$('li').toggle(function() {
    p = $(this).find('p').appendTo('#pane');
}, function() {
    p.appendTo(this);
});
```

The local variable `p` is used to store the reference to the paragraph when it is inside the #pane DIV. This obviously works only for one LI element, because if the user clicks on one LI element and then immediately after that on another LI element, the `p` variable is overwritten with the new paragraph reference.

This is what I would like to do:
Whenever a P element is transfered to the #pane DIV, I want to somehow associate that P element with the LI element that originally contained it, so that when the LI is clicked again, I know which P element I have to transfer back.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way you could do it is with an `each` statement to give each `p` it's own scope. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5y6u/2/)

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var p = $(this).find('p');

    $(this).toggle(
        function() { p.appendTo('#pane'); },
        function() { p.appendTo(this); }
    );
});
```

Comment: I agree this is the best of the two solutions :)

Comment: As long as you don't have too many `<li>` elements, I think it is a good one. Otherwise the overhead would become a bit much.

Answer (score 2):

You could

1. use naming convention for ids: **li**  has the same id as **p** plus **li-** prefix
2. store p id in li's **data-** attribute
3. use the same **css class** for each pair of li / p

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`data()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method and/or the [`jQuery.data()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to give each `<li>` element a reference to its `<p>` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5y6u/3/

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.data('relatedP', $th.find('p'));
})
.toggle(function() {
    $.data(this,'relatedP').appendTo('#pane');
}, function() {
    $.data(this,'relatedP').appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: Storing entire jQuery objects inside data() values? Cool `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, `.data()` can be very handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put your dynamic content in the 'pane' div and toggle the visibility, the logic becomes a bit simpler. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/u5y6u/4/

Bob